# write and read Dictionary Python 3

Tags: python, json, dictionary, weather

I want to write weather information to a file and read it with another script. Currently I'm stuck at writing to file. 
Original Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pprint import pprint
import pywapi
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

steyregg = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('AUXX0022')


pp.pprint(steyregg)
```

this give me output like this:

```
> {   'current_conditions': {   'barometer': {   'direction': u'falling
> rapidly',
>                                                'reading': u'1021.33'},
>                               'dewpoint': u'0',
>                               'feels_like': u'2',
>                               'humidity': u'67',
>                               'icon': u'32',
>                               'text': u'W'}},.......
```

So I tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pprint import pprint
import pywapi
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

steyregg = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('AUXX0022')

with open('weather.txt', 'wt') as out:
    pp.pprint(steyregg, stream=out)
```

But this leads to Error:

```
pprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i read wheater.txt once it works in another python script? Or is there a more elegant way to capture Data like this and use it somewhere else?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pprint` *method* of the [`PrettyPrinter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pprint.html#prettyprinter-objects) class does not accept a `stream` keyword argument.  Either give the stream when you create the object in this line:

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
```

or use the *function* [`pprint.pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint), which accepts a `stream` keyword argument.

That's the reason for the error.  A more fundamental question is: why you are using the `pprint` module, when title of the question is "write and read xml Python 3"?  The `pprint` module does not generate XML.  See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml for some ideas on handling XML with python.

Also note that `pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com` returns a python dictionary.  The function has already converted the XML data into a dictionary, so you don't have to read any XML.  See this [example](http://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/wiki/Examples#Weather.com) (if you haven't already).

You could save the dictionary as a JSON file.

```
import json

with open('weather.txt', 'wt') as out:
    json.dump(steyregg, out, indent=4)
```

Comment: i dont need xml, I thought this would do this, i just want the weather information saved and availaible in another script. Just looking for a way to do this.

Comment: OK. I'll google how to handle the Dictionary. Will have a look on json

Comment: I added a note about JSON to the answer.